# Show that the collection of cylinders form an algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, solution-verification

I am working on an exercise in stochastic process stating that:

> Denote $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ to be the set of all functions $x:\mathbb{T}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is some index sets. Let $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then the cylinder set is defined by $$\mathcal{C}(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B\}.$$ Show that the set of all cylinders form an algebra.

I have some attempt, and I think I showed the closure under complement, but I was stuck in the closure under finite intersection.

Here is my attempt:

Denote $\mathfrak{C}$ to be the collection of all cylinder sets. To show the closure under complement, let $E\in\mathfrak{C}$, then $E$ can be written as $$E=\mathcal{C}(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B\},$$ for some $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}\in\mathbb{T}$.

Then, 
\begin{align*}
E^{c}&=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(y_{t_{1}},\cdots, y_{t_{n}})\notin B\}\\
&=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(y_{t_{1}},\cdots, y_{t_{n}})\in B^{c}\},
\end{align*}
but the complement of a Borel set is still a Borel set, so the last set is still a cylinder set.

Thus, $E^{c}\in\mathfrak{C}$.

**But is it necessary that if $(y_{t_{1}},\cdots, y_{t_{n}})\notin B$ then $(y_{t_{1}},\cdots, y_{t_{n}})\in B^{c}$? if so, why?**

To show the closure under finite intersection, let $C_{1}, C_{2}\in\mathfrak{C}$, then $$C_{1}=\mathcal{C}(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B_{1})=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B_{1}\},$$ $$C_{2}=\mathcal{C}(s_{1},\cdots, s_{n}, B_{2})=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(y_{s_{1}},\cdots, y_{s_{n}})\in B_{2}\},$$ for some $B_{1}, B_{2}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, s_{1}\cdots, s_{n}\in\mathbb{T}$.

Then $$C_{1}\cap C_{2}=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(z_{t_{1}},\cdots, z_{t_{n}})\in B_{1}, (z_{s_{1}},\cdots, z_{s_{n}})\in B_{2}\},$$

**but what I should do next?**

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  the first question you only have to know what $B^{c}$ means. If an element does not belong to $B$ it belongs to $B^{c}$.

For the second question you need the following fact about cylinder sets: $\{(x:x_{t_1},(x:x_{t_2},...,x_{t_n}) \in B$ can be written as $\{x:(x_{t_1},x_{t_2},...,x_{t_n},x_{t_{n+1}}) \in B_1\}$ where $B_1 =B \times \mathbb R$ and $t_{n+1}$ is any point in the index set . 
 Using this repeatedly you observe that we can always increase the indexing set $(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)$ in any cylinder set by suitably modifying the Borel set $B$. The idea now is to write the two given cylinder sets with the same indexing set  (by taking the union of the given indexing sets) and this makes it obvious that their union/intersection is also a cylinder set.

Comment: so I can regard my first proof as correct? I am sorry I don't quite understand your answer for the second part. What is the set $\{(x:x_{t_{1}},(x:x_{t_{2}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B\}$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Your proof for the complement is correct. There was  a typo in the second part . I have corrected it.

Comment: so you mean that we can always write this: $$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}},\cdots,x_{t_{m}})\in B\times\mathbb{R}^{n-m}\},$$ for any points $t_{n+1},\cdots, t_{m}$? I have no doubt in this, but why does this imply that we can write two cylinder sets with the same indexing set?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Just take the indexing sets of the two cylinder sets and take their union. Use this union as the new indexing set for both of them.

Comment: yeah I sort of understand.. but if you increase the indexing set $(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n})$ in this way, do you increase the Borel set $B$ from $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ to a higher dimension $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ for instance? but is the dimension $n$ fixed?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical $n$ is not fixed. $\{x: (x_{t_1} \in B)\}$ and $\{x: (x_{t_1},x_{t_2}) \in B \times \mathbb R\}$ stand for one and the same cylinder set.

Comment: ah! Sorry for coming back again. I just want to let you know I suddenly understand what you meant. If we take the union of to indexing set and use the union as the new indexing set for both of them, then one of them will "lose" some coordinate, but we can use the above identity to "add" in coordinate without changing the set. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a question here. How can we show that empty set or the whole set $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ belongs to the algebra?